# If we have $A = AB$, what can we conclude about $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

If we have matrices $A$ and $B$ ($A$ not necessarily square), and $A = AB$, what can we conclude about $B$? I know that the rank of $B$ needs to be at least the rank of $A$, but I bet more could be said.

As a related question, I'm also curious what are some conditions for $A = AB \Rightarrow B = I$ to be true.

Comment: Since $A$ and $AB$ have the same number of columns, $B$ must be a square matrix.

Comment: If $A$ is invertible then $B$ must be identity (just left multiply both sides by $A^{-1})$. $A=AB$ implies either $A$ not invertible or $B=I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rank of $B$ is at least equal to the rank of $A$, because
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(AB)\le\operatorname{rank}(B)
$$

Now, in order to analyze further the problem, you can assume $A$ is in reduced row echelon form, because if $E$ is an invertible matrix such that $EA$ is in RREF, then $EAB=EA$.

Now consider a permutation matrix $P$ such that $AP$ has the block form
$$
AP=\left[\begin{array}{c|c} I_r & C \\ \hline 0 & 0 \end{array}\right]
$$
(permute the columns in such a way that the pivot columns are at the beginning in the right order to form the block $I_r$, where $r$ is the rank of $A$). Then you have
$$
AP=APP^{-1}BP
$$
and if we decompose $P^{-1}BP$ in compatible blocks
$$
P^{-1}BP=\left[\begin{array}{c|c} B_1 & B_2 \\ \hline B_3 & B_4 \end{array}\right]
$$
we have
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c|c} I_r & C \\ \hline 0 & 0 \end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{c|c} B_1+CB_3 & B_2+CB_4 \\ \hline 0 & 0 \end{array}\right]
$$
and so we need $B_1+CB_3=I_r$ and $B_2+CB_4=C$.

Note: the block $C$ does not exist if $A$ has full column rank; in this case $A$ has a left inverse and $AB=A$ implies $B$ is the identity.

The condition $AB=A$ can also be expressed as $A(B-I)=0$; if $A$ hasn't full column rank then its null space is nonzero; take $v\ne0$ such that $Av=0$ and build the matrix
$$
B=[v\ v\ \dots \ v]+I
$$
Then $AB=A$ and $B\ne I$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your informative response! If it's okay, I do have some questions. 

I'm working with a case where $A$ is a wide matrix and $B = X^+ X$, where $X$ is tall. Since $A$ is wide, its nullspace has to be nonzero. Further, in many cases, $X$ has full column rank, which means that $X^+ X = I$. But that means I get a case of $AB = A$ and $B = I$, although $A$ has nonzero nullspace. This seems to be impossible based off what you said. Does this mean I must be doing something wrong somewhere?

Comment: @MrBear Well… I see no issue with the proof that when $A$ has a nonzero null space then $B$ is not unique.

Comment: Oh I see; you are saying $B = I$ works, but you also constructed other $B$ that work as well. Thanks, and thanks very much for your answer.